# Allow access to SQL Server Management Studio only to admin account

Tags: ssms, windows-authentication

I would like to allow only administrators to access to SQL Server Management Studio using ["Windows autentication"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVkoI.png). How can I avoid simple users to access with Windows autentication? Or in alternative avoid users to open SSMS?

Comment: Setup permissions accordingly but honestly it would be better to just setup the correct database permissions.

Comment: You can revoke read/execute filesystem rights for SSMS executable (or the whole folder) for Windows users who are not Administrators group members. No access - cannot start.